# how to convert mysql_fetch_array in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm a newbie in Codeigniter, I have a problem when I create model in codeigniter with mysql_fetch array. I don't know how to convert mysql_fetch_array in codeigniter?

my model:

```
$auto=mysql_query("select * from penjualan order by nonota desc limit 1");
$no=mysql_fetch_array($auto);
$angka=$no['nonota']+1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try CodeIgniters query builder, there are really good docs [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)
For your example I suggest the following:

```
$query = $this->db->order_by('nonota', 'DESC')
    ->limit(1)
    ->get('penjualan');
if( $query->num_rows() > 0) {
    $result = $query->result(); //or $query->result_array() to get an array
    foreach( $result as $row )
    {
         //access columns as $row->column_name
    }
}
```

Comment: i have followed your code,but i have problem in view with  <?php echo $kode[0]->no_nota;?> can't show

Comment: What kind of error do you get? note that in my example there is nonota and you are using no_nota, is it possible this is a typo? Also did you set $view_data in the controller? Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

$auto=$this->db->select('*')
               ->order_by('nonota','desc')
               ->limit(1)
               ->get('penjualan ');
$no    = $auto->result_array();
$angka = $no[0]['nonota']+1;//for first element in the array index 0;
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.